# How to get the extra large cover image from google book API?

Tags: web-services, google-books

According to Google doc, using this link can get the URL extra large for a book

[Google doc](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#RetrievingVolume)

However, when I clicked https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/zyTCAlFPjgYC , there are only 2 thumbnails (small and medium). So do I need to obtain a Google API key to get full information about a book ?

Answer (score 10):

I figured out that you can replace the `&zoom=1` part of the URL with `&zoom=0` for larger images, but only in some cases.

For an example, this is the Sherlock Holmes small thumbnail:

http://bks5.books.google.com/books?id=buc0AAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api

Now, by setting `zoom` to `0`, I get a large thumbnail:

http://bks5.books.google.com/books?id=buc0AAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=0&edge=curl&source=gbs_api

Comment: You also get the links directly in response to querying for a book, see https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#RetrievingBookshelf, there the response part contains 6 sizes "smallThumbnail" up to "extraLarge", like written here, distinguished by "zoom". 5 and 6 seem to be out of order, perhaps added later.

Comment: Setting zoom to 0, seems to actually just give you the first page of the book. In some cases, that means the picture is vastly different. Check this example: https://books.google.com/books/content?id=ZxZ6_bBKdNcC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api

Answer (score 2):

Actually with some books, google provides large image but some not.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming across this there is a simple way to solve this that works most of the time. You can add `'&fife=w800'` to the end of the request. Leave the zoom as it is. I experimented with really large numbers and found that the api will just give you the biggest image it has up to the number you set. You can also set the height if you need to using `'&fife=h900'` and both with `'&fife=w800-h900'`

Answer (score 0):

set the zoom to 3 instead of 0 or 1 and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Just change zoom size in url.

```js
let img = "https://books.google.com/books/content?id=54BEAAAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"

let imgZoom = img.replace('zoom=1', 'zoom=10')
newImg.src= imgZoom;
```

```html
<img src="" id="newImg">
```